# Why if i subdivide a "piramid" it will be distorted?

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface

I have make a cylinder and i have reduced the mount of vertices to 4 and i have tried to subdivide it but the problem is that  it distorts.
[image]

Comment: please show a screenshot

Comment: By a 4 vertex mesh, did you reduce it down to a tetrahedron?

Comment: I would like to male a tetrahedron but how i Can u see subdividing It, It doesn't work